# Listview in TableLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, listactivity

Is it possible to put a ListView within a table layout?  How would you go about doing this?  I don't think you can call startActivity(myListActivity) because it will pause the activity containing the table layout.  Do I need to make myListActivity an inner class of the tableLayout activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to put a ListView within a table layout?

Not easily, but that is more due to the behavior of `ListView`, not working well with height of `wrap_content`.

> I don't think you can call startActivity(myListActivity) because it will pause the activity containing the table layout.

That would not be putting a `ListView` in a `TableLayout`. That would be putting a `ListView` in a totally separate activity.

Comment: This is helpful but I'm going to hold off on marking this as the correct answer because "Not easily" isn't necessarily the correct answer.  Clarifying why you can't start a list activity in an activity was very helpful.

Comment: @kinger9120: Well, to clarify... AFAIK, it is impossible to have a reliably working `ListView` as a cell in a `TableRow`, because `TableRow` forces children to have height of `wrap_content`, which flat out does not work well with `ListView`. It should be possible to have a `ListView` be an immediate child of `TableLayout`, spanning the whole table width, if you manually set the height to be `match_parent`... but then there will be no room for any other rows. Either switch to a `Spinner` in a table cell or switch away from `TableLayout` to some other container class (e.g., `RelativeLayout`).

Comment: @kinger9120: And if a fixed size works for you, OK. This is generally difficult to manage across multiple screen sizes.